# R ggplot2 for loop plots same data

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I have put together a simple for loop to generate a series of plots and then use grid.arrange to plot them. I have two problems:

1. The axes of the plots change correctly to the column names, but the *same* data is plotted on each graph. Having put in a breakpoint and stepped through the code it appears to be incrementing correctly so I'm not sure why.
2. I have set the plot aesthetic to group on year, however this produces intermediate .5 years that appear in the legend. This hasn't happened to me before.

Should all be reproducible using `mtcars`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

result <- mtcars

for(i in 1:2) {
  nam <- paste("p", i, sep = "")
  assign(
    nam, ggplot(result, aes(x = disp, y = results[i+4], group = gear, color = gear)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Dark2", direction = -1, guide = "legend") +
      scale_y_continuous(name = colnames(results[i+4])) +
      scale_x_continuous(name = "x")
  )
}


plist <- mget(paste0("p", 1:2))
do.call(grid.arrange, plist)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but have you checked `facet_wrap()`? If the data come from the same dataset it might be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think trying to access the columns by their number in the `aes` mapping is confusing ggplot. This works:

```
for(i in 1:2) {
  nam <- paste("p", i, sep = "")
  assign(
    nam, ggplot(result,aes_string(x="disp",y=colnames(result)[i+4], group="gear", color="gear")) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Dark2", direction=-1, guide="legend") +
      scale_y_continuous(name=colnames(result[i+4])) +
      scale_x_continuous(name="x")
  )
}
```

I would suggest iterating over the names though; this makes the code much clearer. Here's a version that does this and skips the detour around the environment:

```
plots <- lapply(c("drat", "wt"), function(column) {
  ggplot(result,aes_string(x="disp",y=column, group="gear", color="gear")) +
    geom_line() + geom_point() +
    scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Dark2", direction=-1, guide="legend") +
    scale_y_continuous(name=column) +
    scale_x_continuous(name="x")}) %>% 
  do.call(grid.arrange, .)
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using results and result. And you should use aes_string and then refer to the variables by string name:

You should also avoid to make tons of assignments. Just put it all into a list()

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

result<-mtcars

for(i in 1:2) {
    nam <- paste("p", i, sep = "")
    assign(
        nam, ggplot(result,aes_string(x="disp",y=names(result)[i+4], group="gear", color="gear")) +
            geom_line() +
            geom_point() +
            scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Dark2", direction=-1, guide="legend") +
            scale_y_continuous(name=colnames(result[i+4])) +
            scale_x_continuous(name="x")
    )
}


plist <- mget(paste0("p", 1:2))
do.call(grid.arrange, plist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plot is generated in the for loop, but evaluated in the do.call. Since `i` has changed in the for loop, both are evaluated with `i = 2`. You can confirm this with:

```
i <- 3
do.call(grid.arrange, plist)
```

A small adjustment to your code fixes the issue:

```
for(i in 1:2) {
  nam <- paste("p", i, sep = "")
  coln <- colnames(result[i+4])
  assign(
    nam, ggplot(result,aes_(x=~disp,y=as.name(coln), group=~gear, color=~gear)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Dark2", direction=-1, guide="legend") +
      scale_y_continuous(name=coln) +
      scale_x_continuous(name="x")
  )
}


plist <- mget(paste0("p", 1:2))
do.call(grid.arrange, plist)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it didnt work - this does exactly as I intended (but didnt understand!)

Comment: P.S. Any idea why the classes add in 0.5 divisions as they arent in the data??

Comment: Yeah, the `gear` column is numeric and is being treated as continuous. You can specify the values to use using the `breaks` parameter. Use `unique` to have separate color for each value of `gear`. In this case, replace the corresponding line with `scale_colour_distiller(breaks = unique(result$gear), palette = "Dark2", direction=-1, guide="legend") +`

Answer (score 0):

You should take full advantage of `ggplot::facet_wrap`

This means tidying your data to a single data frame that's interpretable to ggplot

**Data**

```
temp <- mtcars
```

**Tidy data**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
Names <- map_chr(1:2, ~names(temp)[.x+4])
# "drat" "wt"

data <- map_df(1:2, ~temp[,c("cyl", names(temp)[.x+4])] %>% setNames(c("cyl", "value")), .id="iteration") %>%
          mutate(iteration = Names[as.numeric(iteration)])
```

**plot with facet_wrap**

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=cyl, y=value, label=iteration)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~iteration)
```