# How to add multiple geoms to ggplot using a list (or for loop)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is, is it possible to dynamically create a list of geoms, which I can add to a ggplot, enabling me to plot several, seperate series of data all at once?

**Reproducible Example**

The following code demonstrates my question:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Function to generate fake data
generate_fake_results = function(){
  results = list()
  
  for(i in c(1:10)){
    
    x = c((1+10*i):(10+10*i))
    
    results = append(results, list(data.frame(
      x = as.Date("2000-01-01") + x,
      y = sin(x),
      ylower1 = sin(x) - 0.25,
      ylower2 = sin(x) - 0.5,
      yupper1 = sin(x) + 0.25,
      yupper2 = sin(x) + 0.50
    )
    )
    )
  }
  
  return(results)
}

fake_data = generate_fake_results()


# Function to plot the mean, upper and lower bounds of a model
# The dataset contains two upper and lower bounds; the 80% and 95% confidence interval
predict_margin_func = function(r, color='blue', alpha=0.1){
  return(
    list(
      geom_ribbon(aes(x=as.Date(r$x,"%Y-%m-%d"),
                      ymin=r$ylower1,
                      ymax=r$yupper1), fill=color, alpha=alpha),
      geom_ribbon(aes(x=as.Date(r$x,"%Y-%m-%d"),
                      ymin=r$ylower2,
                      ymax=r$yupper2), fill=color, alpha=alpha),
      geom_line(aes(x=as.Date(r$x,"%Y-%m-%d"), y=r$y), size=1.25, color=color)
    )
  )
}



# This plots the graph that I want, but... I have to manually add each forecast 
# from my fake_data list "manually"
ggplot() +
  predict_margin_func(fake_data[[1]]) + 
  predict_margin_func(fake_data[[2]]) + 
  predict_margin_func(fake_data[[3]]) +
  predict_margin_func(fake_data[[4]]) +
  predict_margin_func(fake_data[[5]])


# I'd rather use a for loop to do this dynamically, but I can't get it to work.
# If I do this, it doesn't work:
plot_list = list()
for(i in c(1:length(fake_data))){
  plot_list = append(plot_list, predict_margin_func(fake_data[[i]]))
}

ggplot() +
  plot_list
```

While solution 1 "works", I'd much rather use something like solution 2, where I don't have to manually add each series I want to plot, as this is more easily extendible if the number of forecasts in the results list changes.

The results in plot_list seem to be 10 copies of the last result/the highest `i` from the for loop. I'm quessing R is doing some clever trick, which I don't want in this specific case, where the results in the list are instances/references of a thing, where I want "the thing that is being referenced too".

Does anyone have an idea what I could do here? I could maybe also reshape my data, but I wondered if it were possible to do using a list.

Comment: Have you tried: `plot <- ggplot()`, then doing `plot <- plot + predict_margin_func(...)` inside the loop?

Comment: @GregorThomas, not true, one can add a list of geoms: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + lapply(c(4,6,8), function(CYL) geom_point(data = ~ subset(., cyl == CYL), color = CYL))` works (though there are obviously better ways to do _that_).

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that you cannot add a list of lists of geoms ... *edit*, nope, that works just fine too.

Comment: @ImpactGuide, is there a reason you cannot combine the data (with some clear ID) and `facet_*` or `group=` on that id?

Comment: Regardless, I can reproduce your manual plot with `ggplot() + lapply(fake_data, predict_margin_func)` (once I rename `fake_results` to `fake_data`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front: I can fix your `for` loop (see below), but I think a better solution is to do:

```r
ggplot() + lapply(fake_data, predict_margin_func)
```

[image]

---

As to why your `for` loop is failing ...

`ggplot` tends to operate *lazily*, so the `[[i]]` is being realized at the time it is rendered, not when the geom is created. This is why you're only seeing the last of them. While [R ggplot2 for loop plots same data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46058055/3358272) appears to be a similar question, the proposed answers don't really apply. Why? Because you're hard-coding values into your geoms instead of assigning `data=` within them and using non-standard evaluation within the geom itself.

Here, I add `data=r` to each geom and remove their references to `r$`.

```r
predict_margin_func2 = function(r, color='blue', alpha=0.1){
  return(
    list(
      geom_ribbon(data = r, aes(x=as.Date(x,"%Y-%m-%d"),
                      ymin=ylower1,
                      ymax=yupper1), fill=color, alpha=alpha),
      geom_ribbon(data = r, aes(x=as.Date(x,"%Y-%m-%d"),
                      ymin=ylower2,
                      ymax=yupper2), fill=color, alpha=alpha),
      geom_line(data = r, aes(x=as.Date(x,"%Y-%m-%d"), y=y), size=1.25, color=color)
    )
  )
}
plot_list = list()
for(i in c(1:length(fake_data))){
  plot_list = append(plot_list, predict_margin_func2(fake_data[[i]]))
}
ggplot() + plot_list
```

(produces the same plot as above).

Comment: Hi r2evans! Thank you so much for the answer, especially the insightful context. I was so stuck thinking in terms of the for-loop, I had completely forgotten about lapply. But even I did remember, I wouldn't have understood why that suddenly worked. The context about the lazy evaluation and about my function hard coding values into the geoms and using non standard evaluation, is really super valuable.